# What is the best way to make a page only accessible through localhost?

Tags: node.js, config

Working on node app and want to make the contents of a page only available when on localhost. What is the best way/best practices to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put local ip restriction (eg 127.0.0.1)

refer to this stackoverflow link for more info on how to do it

[Restrict access to Node.js-based HTTP server by IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349251/restrict-access-to-node-js-based-http-server-by-ip-address)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Express, you can use this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
...
app.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');
```

You can find more detailed explanation about this feature here: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.listen

You can also achieve this with adding a rule in your firewall that will allow only connections from localhost.

Comment: not using express and I want to specify it on the application layer

Comment: The example I provided is also identical with Node’s `http.Server.listen()`. I will try to give you more precise answer if you provide more technical details.