# How do I identify two requests from the same source in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, http, express, ipv4, ddos

my case is simple:

I need an application layer solution to identify and then apply some sort of rule to requests coming from the same origin.

If a guy will request my server from Postman, or from a browser or from a cURL I want to identify this guy and then do something with this information.

In my particular case I want to blacklist a guy who would be attacking my server for sometime.

Is it possible in Node/Express?

Comment: How are you defining origin?  IP Address?  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349251/restrict-access-to-node-js-based-http-server-by-ip-address

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no uber identifier that comes with a web request that tells you who the user is behind the request, no matter how the request was initiated (browser, cURL, Postman, node.js app, PHP app, etc...).

This question comes up pretty regularly among new web developers.  In the end it boils down to two things:

1. Requiring users to have an account, login to that account in order to use your service, requiring login credentials with every use of the service and then tracking their usage to see if it meets your usage guidelines.  If it does not, you can ban that account.
2. Rate limiting users either by account or by IP address or some combination of both.  If they exceed a certain rate limit, you can slow them down or deny access.

A browser provides a cookie so you can attempt to identify repeat users via browser cookies.  But, this can be defeated by clearing cookies.  Cookies are per-browser though so you can't correlate the same user across multiple devices or across multiple browsers with a plain cookie.

cURL and Postman don't provide any identifying information by default other than the originating IP address.  You can attempt to track IP address, but there are some issues with relying only on IP address because corporate users may be going through a proxy which makes them all appear to come from the same IP address.  If you ban one user for misbehavior, that may affect lots of other innocent users.

If you look how Google, Facebook, etc... do this, they all require you to create some sort of account and then provide credentials for that account with every request.  This allows them to track your usage and manage your traffic if needed.  And, for free usage, they generally all have rate limits that limit how frequently you can make API calls.  This prevents any single user from using more than an appropriate share of the load of the service.  And, it allows them to detect and regulate accounts that are abusing the system.

One step further than this concerns how an account is created because you don't want an abuser to just be able to run a script every 10 minutes to automatically create a new account.  There are a variety of schemes for protecting this too.  The most common is just requiring some proof that a human is involved in creating the new account (captcha, question/answer, etc...) which prevent automated account creation.  Other checks can require a valid credit card, unique email address verification, etc...

Comment: alright, I see the whole problem now. we were thinking about sessions/tokens, but it is yet not implemented. I get a question regarding proxies. so you are telling me that banning a IP would prevent a big group of innocent users from requiring our stuff right? but this is not only due to proxies, right? I mean, in my country at least (and I think any other work the same way) a group of close internet users are given the same public IP address, that is the router/switch to which they are connected. this is geographically related, but also a problem, right? not only proxies (in terms of ip ban)

Comment: @VictorFerreira - Yes, any case where an IP address is shared among multiple users can cause problems with tracking based solely on IP address.  A corporate proxy is just one case of this, but enough of an issue to make you  need to avoid it.