# How to allow access from certain IP to certain endpoints in Azure?

Tags: azure, security, networking, cloud, endpoint

I have App Service which is classic web app written in Node.js. Let's say that my app have 2 endpoints: /**SecuredEndpoint** and /**ClassicEndpoint**. /**SecuredEndpoint** should be secured, meaning only certain IP addresses are allowed to access it. **ClassicEndpoint** on the other hand is public to whole internet.

I've found out that in Azure I can specify Access Restrictions to **whole** service for certain IP addresses (I can block/allow access based on IP address). But I would like to secure not the whole app but only certain endpoints.

Can someone help me how can I achieve that in Azure?

Answer (score 1):

To restrict certain IP addresses is to restrict ACL in the networking layer. [Access Restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions) are effectively network ACLs. However, it is implemented in the App Service front-end roles, which are upstream of the worker hosts where your code runs. In this case, you could consider selecting to use two app services for each endpoint. You can read supported [security in the Azure app service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-security).

Alternatively, you may allow certain IP addresses in your special code. Google some samples for such a feature. It might be like [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349251/restrict-access-to-node-js-based-http-server-by-ip-address/51021945). For App Service on Windows, you can also restrict IP addresses dynamically by configuring the web.config. For more information, see [Dynamic IP Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/security/dynamicIpSecurity/).

In addition, If you are interested in securing Back-end App Service Web Apps with VNets and Service Endpoints, you could have a look at [this blog](https://markheath.net/post/securing-backend-appservice-webapps).