# Is there a way to prevent access to localhost:3000 from other devices on network?

Tags: node.js, express, http

I am using express.js to run a http server. Is there a way to prevent other devices on my network to able to access the port 3000 via my IP address?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restrict access to Node.js-based HTTP server by IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349251/restrict-access-to-node-js-based-http-server-by-ip-address)

Answer (score 1):

Your service running on port 3000 is probably binding to 0.0.0.0 or 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0, that makes it so it is accessible from any available address.

To restrict access to your service running on port 3000 and make it accessible only in the machine where it's running you need to modify its configuration to make it bind only to the localhost address. For IPv4 it's 127.0.0.1, and for IPv6 it's 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1.

The process for making this change depends on the specific server or service that you are running.