# Force node.js socket.io 2.4 to listen to 127.0.0.1

Tags: node.js, express, google-chrome-extension, websocket, socket.io

I have a Node.js Socket.io `v2.4` server that I want to restrict its access. I want only a particular chrome extension to be able to connect to it and nothing else. I noticed that traffic from Chrome Extension shows up as `127.0.0.1` as opposed to other traffic from localhost shows up as `localhost`. I know there are other ways like Interprocess Communication (IPC) that might be better than communication over websockets and http, but I can not use those at the moment.

Here are the pertinent parts of the node.js server code:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var path = require('path');
    var app = express();

    var server = require('http').createServer({
      requestCert: false,
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    }, app);

    var io = require('socket.io')(server);
    var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

    //511 is backlog, which Specifies the max length of the queue of pending connections. Default 511
    server.listen(port, '127.0.0.1', 511, function () {
        console.log('[server] listening at port %d', port);
    });
```

I thought this would only listen to requests from `127.0.0.1`, but it seems to accept requests from any website loading in the browser.
Any help is most appreciated .. thank you

Comment: FYI: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12349448/1207049

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restrict access to Node.js-based HTTP server by IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349251/restrict-access-to-node-js-based-http-server-by-ip-address)