# Node.js Restrict HTTP server to be accessible only on 127.0.0.1

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, firewall, ws

I have created a [ws websocket server in nodejs](https://github.com/websockets/ws#external-https-server) and a http server that is listening on a specific port and host is 127.0.0.1. WebSocket server connection is established on the upgrade event emitted by the http server.
For security purpose I want the server to be accessible only on localhost/127.0.0.1 and not from 0.0.0.0 IP.

Example:

1. ws://0.0.0.0:5050 - Should not accept connections
2. ws://127.0.0.1:5050 - Should accept connections

How can I restrict the server to be only reachable from localhost and not from any other IP(including 0.0.0.0)?

```
const server = http.createServer();
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ noServer: true });
server.listen(5050, '127.0.0.1');

server.on('upgrade', function (request, socket, head) {
  wss.handleUpgrade(request, socket, head, function (ws) {
  //conditional checks
  wss.emit('connection', ws, request);
  })
})
```

Can somebody please direct me to the proper way of doing this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restrict access to Node.js-based HTTP server by IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349251/restrict-access-to-node-js-based-http-server-by-ip-address)

Comment: Simple solution would be add a check using request that is being sent,in which you can check the IP address in express it can be done using  "req.ip"

Comment: @ArtemArkhipov I tried the solution mentioned but none of them seem to work for me. Actually I am creating a ws websocket server which is using the http server in the noServer mode. May be this is the reason. Ref https://github.com/websockets/ws#external-https-server

Comment: @SwarupChavan I am not using express.

Comment: Even if its not express, you still get a `request` which will probably contain the IP address you can filter on? (Express is just a small wrapper for some functionality anyway)

Comment: can you try with request.socket.remoteAddress

Comment: @SwarupChavan Even if I make a request from 0.0.0.0, request.socket.remoteAddress returns me 127.0.0.1. I am checking this in upgrade event.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(req.socket.remoteAddress !== '127.0.0.1'){
res.send('403 Access Denied');
res.end();
} else { 
// allow access
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit, this looks promising but notice that the OP isn't using express and in his handlers does not have the usual `res` or necessarily normal `req` object.

Comment: Even if I make a request from 0.0.0.0, request.socket.remoteAddress returns me 127.0.0.1. I am checking this in upgrade event.

Answer (score 0):

[`0.0.0.0`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0) isn't an IP address. It is a non-routable meta-address used to designate an invalid, unknown or non-applicable target.

You might have a client that treats requests to `0.0.0.0` as being intended for localhost, but that isn't a security problem since your server still won't be accessible outside of the current machine.

Your existing code, where you only listen on `127.0.0.1` is sufficient.

Comment: Basically, the app I am developing is going to be installed in the client's machine. When a server binds to the address 0.0.0.0, it allows connections from every IP address on the local machine, effectively exposing the server to every possible network. When the server is listening on 0.0.0.0, an unauthenticated attacker may be able to connect and send messages to the socket server without the consent. This may lead to the disclosure of sensitive information.

Comment: @JaspreetChhabra — `server.listen(5050, '127.0.0.1');` — you **aren't** doing that though. (As I pointed out in the third paragraph of this answer).

Comment: Right but when I am making a request using "ws://0.0.0.0:5050", it does accepts the connection.

Comment: @JaspreetChhabra — I refer you to the second paragraph of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Access and security that you are talking about are supposed to be done at the firewall of your instance hosting nodejs server.

However, if you still want to implement it on your nodejs layer you can dig the request object there you will find the IP address from where the request is coming, and based on that you can take your action.

Hope it helps, Thank you